# Gitlab Reconfigure error cannot load such file syslog-logger

Tags: ruby, gitlab

I already tried to search on Google about my problem but still no luck. My server just got recovered and now I can't access Gitlab-CE. Every time I use command `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` the error happen.

Here's the output of error:

```
    $ sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- syslog-logger (LoadError)
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.6.4/lib/chef/log/syslog.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.6.4/lib/chef/log.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.6.4/lib/chef.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.6.4/bin/chef-client:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you recently change anything in your gitlab.rb? What version of GitLab are you running?

Comment: i didn't change anything in gitlab.rb but my server just recovered from kernel panick before. My SysAdmin just do fsck and everything suddenly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have actual file system corruption in a file related to the [Syslog:Logger](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/syslog/rdoc/Syslog/Logger.html).

You could step through those files and update or replace them, but honestly it would be easier to spin up another virtual server, re-install gitlab-ce from scratch, and restore from your previous (nightly?) backup.